# Testing CORS with the Postman tool/ cURL/ in Chrome console

Tags: curl, cors, google-chrome-devtools, postman

I'm testing CORS with the Postman tool and I constantly get

```
access-control-allow-origin → null
```

for `GET` or `OPTIONS` requests to

```
http://localhost:4000/api/accounts?Host=http://localhost:4200/&X-Origin=http://jquery.com
```

Also using `Origin` instead of `X-Origin` doesn't change the outcome.
Meanwhile, if I use cURL like this

```
 curl -H "Origin: http://jquery.com" --verbose http://localhost:4000/api/accounts
```

I do gain access to the API

```
< access-control-allow-origin: http://jquery.com
```

I've also opened the jQuery website using `http` and the chrome Javascript console in order to execute this code:

```
$.get("http://localhost:4000/api/accounts").then(function(val){console.log(val);})
```

And it printed the JSON object returned by the API.

Now my questions are as follows:

1. How can I properly test CORS using Postman? I've noticed that when set the allow origins option on the server to `*` Postman does return

   `access-control-allow-origin → *`

The problem mentioned above appears only when I explicitly allow a set of origins like:

```
`origin: ["https://www.getpostman.com/", "http://localhost:4200/", "http://jquery.com"]`
```

2. I noticed that allowing `http://jquery.com/` instead of `http://jquery.com` will not allow requests from which the origin is `Origin=http://jquery.com`?
3. I've noticed that cURL returns the contents of the resource (in this case JSON data) even if the request comes from non-authorized origin. Is this normal or does it mean that I forgot to configure something on the server that exposes this data?

Answer (score 36):

You can try

```
curl -X OPTIONS 'https://domain/path/file.png' -H "Origin: https://yoursitedomain" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -v -o /dev/null
```

Answer (score 18):

The `Origin` header sent from the client is the scheme, domain and port (if not 80), from which the request originates. The trailing `/` is not valid in the header. You cannot send multiple origins either. The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` sent from the server can either be `*`, allowing all origins, or you send back the same origin from the request header.

For example, if you make a request to `http://www.telerik.com/` in Chrome, the request header contains `Origin:http://www.telerik.com` (the browser automatically sends this), and the response header from the server contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.telerik.com`.

As for your last question, according to the specification, the user agent is responsible for enforcing CORS, so I suspect cURL doesn't validate that the request and response match.

> The user agent validates that the value and origin of where the
>   request originated match.

**Source:** https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Answer (score 0):

based on [nicks-cors-test](https://github.com/njgibbon/nicks-cors-test)
you can test inside browser console with simple js :
just need jquery as dependency, and replace `DEST_URL_ADDRESS` with url

```
function main() 
{
    console.log("nicks-cors-test");
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "DEST_URL_ADDRESS",
        success: function(data) 
        {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

and then run `main();` also you can run without any dependency only browser console

```
fetch('DEST_URL_ADDRESS') 
   .then(resp => resp.json()) 
   .catch(err => { 
         console.log('error'); console.log(err);
    });
```